# is it possible to surgically connecting or add functional new elbow to someone arms?

Tags: science-based, biology, anatomy

example image from One piece by Eichiro Oda

[image]

inspired by this [Texas doctors sew man's hand to abdomen to save fingers](https://www.cbc.ca/news/health/texas-doctors-sew-man-s-hand-to-abdomen-to-save-fingers-1.3212997) (i know it actually merge with the abdoment, but the image make it look like it was attaching another hand over his lose hand.)

so a mad man try to surgically attaching or modifying new elbow to his patient (doesnt need to be similar size for the new elbow like it have bigger or smaller bicep for example), is it possible ? can the arm move after surgical/recovery complete?

just assume the mad man is very skilled and have the best equipment either modern or futuristic.

feel free to suggest another solution if surgical method is impossible outside of genetic enginering or birth defect and mechanical like cyborg.

Answer (score 3):

The picture you've shown there doesn't appear to be an elbow as such. Elbows only offer a single degree of freedom, and an arm with two elbows with parallel axes wouldn't be particularly useful as a result... the upper arm, mid-arm and forearm would all be in the same plane, so all you'd get is a weaker, bendier limb, possibly with greater reach (depending on how you grafted it).

Looking at the subject's arms you can see that the mid-arm seems to be able to rotate as well as flex, because the forearms and the upper arms aren't in the same plane. What you've got there is an entirely *new* kind of limb section, with either a two-boned midlimb connecting to a two-boned forearm (which would be a very complex joint more like a wrist or ankle than an elbow) or some kind of ball-and-socket upper elbow which doesn't have any equivalent in terrestrial animal bodyplans, as far as I'm aware.

Whether or not a conventional elbow could be spliced into place is one question (answered nicely enough by Demigan) but to create an entirely new kind of joint, graft it to a person and have it be not merely useable (eg. not immediately break, seize up, fill with scar tissue) and then be useable by a regular human, somehow... seems dubious, to say the least!

Comment: hmm....mine actually just the conventional elbows attached to another one,  the image just an example so dont take it to literally, but thanks for the information though at least i learn something new, but im curious does it possible biologicaly or genetically/anatomically/musculatory to form such new kind of limbs that you describe ?

Comment: @LiJun developmental anomalies in the foetus might cause weird multijointed limbs to arise... maybe via genetic engineering, maybe via exposure to teratogens. The result is not likely to work well though; it'll be weak and probably clumsy

Comment: I think perspective is playing a trick on you. The arms are in the same plane, the way they are displayed is simply because it's a cartoon and the hands are far closer to the screen. The way they are positioned is because of the shoulder and the fact that the radius and ulna can still rotate around each other. Even with a lower arm resection where you then add the upper+lower arm of another patient you'd have 1 radius and ulna to rotate around each other.

Answer (score 2):

Since we can re-attach hands it should be theoretically possible. It would require taking immunosuppressants for the rest of your life and high chances of rejection and severe enough infection to die. It would also require the surgeons to not just re-attach the hand to existing muscles and nerves but to clean most of the hand-muscles from the newly dubbed middle arm, add some larger biceps+triceps lije muscles preferably harvested from the upper donor arm that attach to the second lower arm and attach it there.

Since you cant just randomly add nerves you will have to re-orient a few nerves to attach to the newly added muscle groups and extent the nerves of the hand muscles with grafts to reach the "new" hand muscles. Re-orienting the nerves has been done for arm-based injuries where nerves for the tongue were attached to the arm. After some learning the subjects can seperate that certain tongue movements dont move the arm and vice versa. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1201001/

It is theoretically possible... but I dont think we will be there yet for a long time. This is head transplant level of surgery. Even "normal" hand re-attachment can take triple the time of a difficult heart surgery!